# Extract specific properties and their values from an object

Tags: javascript, object, frontend, data-manipulation

Let's say I have this obj:

```
let userInfo = {
    name: 'Ahmed',
    age: 24,
    _id: "34ef5576",
    email: 'ahmed@gmail.com'
}
```

how can i extract the properties **name**, **_id**, and **email**. And put them in a new Object?
thanks.

So I want a simple way to solve this without any external libraries..!

Comment: In addition to the already given answers, the OP also might have a look into [_destructuring assignment_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) ... as for the OP's use case ... `const { name, _id, email } = userInfo;`

Comment: ... regarding the OP's last edit changes ... _"And put them in a new Object?"_ ... write a function which accepts an object and does create and return the specific object ... like ... `function createVitalUserDate({ _id, name, email }) { return { _id, name, email }; } const vitalUserDate = createVitalUserDate(userInfo);`... or even as immediately invoked unnamed [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) ... `const vitalUserDate = (({ _id, name, email }) => ({ _id, name, email }))(userInfo);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I find it:

1. let's say we have this Object, The original Object that we want to extract from its specific Fields:

   ```
   const parentObj = { name: "ahmed", age: 22, country: "morocco" };
   ```
2. Now we are creating a function that creates for us the extract object:

   ```
   function pickFromObj(originalObject, arrayOfWantedProperties){
     let resultObj = {};
     for(property in originalObject){
       if(arrayOfWantedProperties.includes(property)){
         resultObj[property] = originalObject[property]
       }
     }
     return resultObj;
   }
   ```
3. Finally Create the extract Object:

   ```
   let childObj = pickFromObj(parentObj, ['name', 'age']);
   ```

Comment: Just from your own answer it became clear what you really wanted to achieve. When asking a Q try to explain as exactly as possible what your problem is and what you expect a from a possible solution. Second, a generic function which picks an object's (maybe even own) properties can or should be implemented more straightforward and a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Learn about property accessors. This is considered basic syntax. If you take a beginner level course or tutorial somewhere about JavaScript, they have possibly told you what they are.

Here you go, take your seat on the train of free web knowledge: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Hint: lots of programming language out there accessing properties/attributes in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Use . To get value

Example

```
// For Get values from an Obj
console.log('Name : ', userInfo.name)
console.log('ID : ', userInfo._id)

// Output
// Name :  Ahmed
// ID :  34ef5576
```